# Community.CsharpSqlLite create database?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database if it doesn't exist but I can't work out how to do it.

When I run

```
_connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + _path);
_connection.Open ();
```

I just get a

```
Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteSyntaxException: unable to open database file
```

The native driver will create when you open a connection to a file that doesn't exist..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding 'New=True;' to the SQLite connection string.

`_connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + _path + ";New=True;");`

Comment: Thanks, where did you find this information? I couldn't find any proper documentation

Comment: This website is good for looking up connection strings in general, and SQLite in particular: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that website.. It talks of SQLite.NET which isn't exactly what I'm using, be nice if the Community.CsharpSqlite package had some proper documentation :(